# Showing Multiple Custom Posts On Category Page With Pagination - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, pagination, categories

I am trying to add two custom post types to an archive.php page by adjusting the loop and adding a query. So far my query works as in it shows both post types and splits the pages in to paginated pages. However, when I click to page 2 of the category it shows a blank page. Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = query_posts(array(
'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
'paged'=>$paged, 
'post_type' => array('podcasts','post'),
));
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- LOOP CONTENTS -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php numeric_bootstrap_posts_nav(); ?>
```